# Pattern that restricts user to enter special characters for first character

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have a requirement for an input field that should allow numbers, alphabets, and special characters like `#`,`$`,`%`,`^` etc. But with only one condition the first character that I enter in the text box should not be a special character.

**Example:**

1. @Test123  --Invalid character
2. Test@123  --Valid  character
3. T@est123% --Valid character

**I tried this**

```
ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)([a-zA-Z0-9 &()_+@&\-=\\|,.\/?\s]+)$/"
```

But not working.

Comment: You did not add the `@` and `%` symbols to the second character class. Maybe a better expression will look like [`/^[a-zA-Z0-9][A-Za-z0-9_!-,.-\/:-@[-\`{-~-]*$/`](https://regex101.com/r/0O6koU/1)

Comment: BTW, if you do not care what chars there will be after the first one, use `ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]/"`. Do not forget to add `ng-trim="false"` if you do not want to allow leading/trailing whitespace in the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

`ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+[^]*$/"`

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+` means one of alphabet or number and

`[^]*` means everything

Comment: Just out of curiousity: why not `^[\w&[^_]].*$`? Of course if `_` does not have to be excluded than you don't need the intersection.